# Wagtail custom wagtailadmin/templates/shared/field.html gives test errors

Tags: wagtail

Wagtail custom wagtailadmin/templates/shared/field.html gives test errors

error is

django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'icon' received unexpected keyword argument 'classname'

Comment: What version of Wagtail are you using? Is this a new project or an upgrade? And what are you doing when you see that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed test by using new wagtail 4.2.2 field.html instead of custom field.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).